# Why does NLTK WordNet fail finding simple words?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I'd like to write a simple function to see if this word 'exists' in WordNet via NLTK.

```
def is_known(word):
    """return True if this word "exists" in WordNet
       (or at least in nltk.corpus.stopwords)."""
    if word.lower() in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'):
        return True
    synset = wn.synsets(word)
    if len(synset) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Why would words like `could, since, without, although` return False? Don't they appear in WordNet? Is there any better way to find out whether a word exists in WN (using NLTK)?

My first try was to eliminate "stopwords" which are words like `to, if, when, then, I, you`, but there are still very common words (like `could`) which I can't find.

Comment: Why do you return True when it's a stopword?

Comment: That was only a try to ignore these words. But i noticed that not all common words are stopwords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WordNet does not contain these words or words like them. For an explanation, see the following from the [WordNet docs](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/frequently-asked-questions/database/):

```
Q. Why is WordNet missing: of, an, the, and, about, above, because, etc.
A. WordNet only contains "open-class words": nouns, verbs, adjectives, and adverbs. Thus, excluded words include determiners, prepositions, pronouns, conjunctions, and particles.
```

You also won't find these kinds of words in the online version of WordNet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract all the lemmas in wordnet and then check against that list:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from itertools import chain
all_lemmas = set(chain(*[i.lemma_names for i in wn.all_synsets()]))

def in_wordnet(word):
  return True if word in all_lemmas else False

print in_wordnet('can')
print in_wordnet('could')
```

**[out]:**

```
True
False
```

Do note that wordnet contains lemmas and not words. Also do note that a word/lemma can be polysemous and not a really a contain word, e.g.

`I can foo bar.` vs `The water can is heavy`

Comment: in_wordnet gives me the same results as is_known but is very slow (not the function itself of course)